# Why is address considered a pointer?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

```
char list[] = "World";
char *ptr = list + 2;
char **p = &ptr;
```

The question: Why is `&ptr` of type `char**`? I understand that `p` points to a pointer to an array but isn't the address of `ptr` a `char*`?

I have looked at [Is an array name a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c), is it possible that the array is considered a pointer as well in this case?

Comment: If `ptr` is a `char*` then its address is a `(char*)*`, i.e. a `char**`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is array considered a pointer also?

No, pointers and arrays are distinct types. The confusion arises partly because in many cases pointers can *decay* to arrays, and in functions, array-like parameters are *adjusted* to pointers.

> Why is &ptr of type char**?

Because `ptr` is of type `char*`. Applying the address-of operator to an object of a type gives you a pointer to that type.

> I understand that p points to a pointer to an array

No, it points to a pointer, which points to an element of an array.

A pointer to an array is a different type altogether. For example, here a real pointer to an array is made to point to an array:

```
int a[8];
int (*arr)[8] = &a;
```

Comment: No, the OP is correct: `char **p = &ptr;` initializes `p` as a pointer to an array, not to an element of an array.

Comment: If you are drawing a firm distinction between "pointer" and "array," then sure. But in neither case is `p` a pointer to an element of an array. It's a pointer to a pointer to an element.

Comment: @TimPierce I am drawing a firm distinction, that is the whole point.

Comment: Your new edit was the one that I wanted to show earlier. :)

Comment: @Haris Thanks fixed. I got confused between `p` and `ptr`.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks for the answer! So in your example, each pointer in arr would correspond to the element in a?

Comment: @JMarcusCham No, `arr` is a *single pointer* to an array of 8 ints. The syntax takes some getting used to.

Comment: @juanchopanza Hmm, then writing int *arr = &a; would be the same no?

Comment: @JMarcusCham I think you missed the whole point of my answer. `int* arr` is a pointer to a single `int`. `int (*arr)[8]` is a pointer to an array of 8 `ints`.

Comment: @juanchopanza ok got it!

Answer (score 2):

You have to follow things step-wise to easily understand this.

`char* ptr` is a `pointer to char` because it is pointing to a `char`.

---

*What is `p` pointing at?*

It is pointing at a `char*`. Therefore, it is a `pointer to a pointer to a char`. That is `p` is of type `char**`.

Answer (score 1):

`&ptr` is a `char **` simply because `ptr` is a `char*`. `list` is not a pointer, it's an array. But `ptr` is declared as `char *`, so it's a pointer.

`ptr` is initialised from a pointer `list + 2`. The expression `list + 2` uses the operator `+`, which performs the array-to-pointer conversion on its operands (if applicable). Therefore, when evaluating `list + 2`, a temporary pointer to `char` is created from `list` using the array-to-pointer conversion. Then another temporary pointer is created by adding `2` to the first one, and this second temporary is then used to initialise `ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

An array's name "decays" into a pointer to its first element under most circumstances.

In this case, the array consists of 2 bytes. Its name `list` is a `char *` pointing to the `W`.

Consequently, `list + 2` points to the `r`. This pointer is stored into `ptr`, a `char *` as well.

A `char *` is a pointer to char. Consequently, a `char **` is a pointer to a pointer to char, and that's exactly what `&ptr` is.

Answer (score 1):

Array is not a pointer. It is an array. However, array can `decay` to pointer in certain contexts, of which most notable is passing an array to a function.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is also the first element of an array, so the address of the first element of the array and the pointer of the array would be the same